# How can I use Optional Image Inputs in BuildConfig

Tags: openshift

As documented in https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/builds/creating-build-inputs.html#image-source_creating-build-inputs I have configured an Image source for my BuildConfig:

```
      source:
        images:
          - from:
              kind: ImageStreamTag
              name: optional-data-image:latest
            paths:
              - sourcePath: /.
                destinationDir: "image-sources/optional-data-dir"
```

When I start the above build it fails to start with the below message

```
Warning BuildConfigInstantiateFailed    6m26s   buildconfig-controller  error instantiating Build from BuildConfig next/site (0): Build.build.openshift.io "my-build-1" is invalid: [spec.source.images[1].from.name: Required value]
```

Is there a way to specify an optional Image Input so that if the image does not exist the build to still continue normally?

Answer (score 0):

Your build has failed because you did not specifiy `from`.

```
strategy:
    type: Source
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: ImageStreamTag
        namespace: openshift
        name: 'java:8'
```

Comment: Maybe I did not phrase the question well, but I did specify `from`, the problem is that in my case the image 'java:8' did not exist. And I would want for the build to proceed normally even when the image does not exist. However, I get the feeling that this is not possible with OCP image inputs.

Comment: Hi Georgios, Even i feel the same because ''from'' act as the base image for the build's inputs.

Comment: Agree. I might create a feature request to OCP, however, for the time being I resorted to a workaround where I conditionally remove the entire section (using Ansible-based Operator). In this case I had an S2I build with 4 optional image sources.